# OFFSET in sparql

Tags: sparql

I have a request to **count the number** of records; the request returns 129980 records

```
SELECT count distinct ?url
  WHERE {
  ?url a dbo:Film.
  }
```

because each time SPARQL returns only 10000 records; So I have to use "offset".

```
SELECT distinct ?url
  WHERE {
  ?url a dbo:Film.
  }limit 10000 offset 1000
```

Question: if I want to take all the records, I need to set offset =12; But why when I set offset = 1000 I still got 1000 records. 
Thank for your responding so much. I appreciate your help.

Comment: what? offset shifts the cursor to the position you mention. I don"t understand what you mean by `offset=12` but `limit 10000 offset 1000` is obviously wrong ... it should be `limit 1000 offset 1000` which in fact return the result 1001 - 2000. Note, the correct usage of offset needs an `order by` clause although some triple stores most likely return an internally ordered resultset.

Comment: and there is no need for `distinct` in your query - I hope it's clear why

Comment: I got it. I fixed my problems. Thank for your responding so much.

Comment: You could provide an answer with your solution. This might help other people having similar issues. Thank's

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that your first query uses invalid SPARQL syntax. You only get a result because the engine you're querying (if you're querying DBpedia, as it appears, that's Virtuoso) is very forgiving of many errors.  Correct and complete syntax would be --

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ( COUNT ( DISTINCT ?url ) AS ?HowManyFilms )
  WHERE {
  ?url a dbo:Film .
  }
```

Things to know, for your second query --

1. `OFFSET` means "skip this many rows from the total result set"
2. `LIMIT` means "only give me this many rows (starting after any `OFFSET`)"
3. Rows may be delivered in any order, and this ordering may change from query-to-query, if you don't include an `ORDER BY`. This can mean that multiple queries with different `OFFSET` may not get you all rows, and may deliver duplicate rows, when all the partial result sets are combined. So -- anytime you're using `OFFSET` and/or `LIMIT`, it's best practice to also use an `ORDER BY`.

All together, add this to the first query to get the first 10,000 rows--

```
ORDER BY ?url LIMIT 10000 OFFSET 0
```

-- and this to get the last 9,980 rows --

```
ORDER BY ?url LIMIT 10000 OFFSET 120000
```

I leave the intermediary queries for you...

Comment: @MinhNguyễn - Please accept my answer, or write your own if it differs substantially.

Comment: Thank TallTed. You are completely right. "Order by" help me avoid to repeat records. Your answers are all that I want. Thank you so much.

Comment: TallTed. I did. I did not know about this :)). Thank you so much

Comment: `Virtuoso 22023 Error SR353: Sorted TOP clause specifies more then 130000 rows to sort. Only 40000 are allowed. Either decrease the offset and/or row count or use a scrollable cursor`

Comment: @fetahokey -- Unless [this page](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtTipsAndTricksHowToHandleBandwidthLimitExceed) is sufficient to resolve your issue, your needs will probably not be well addressed in SO comments.  In such case, I suggest that you pose your question on the [OpenLink Community Forum](https://community.openlinksw.com/) or as an [issue on the Virtuoso project on GitHub](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/).

Comment: @TallTed 
I prevent this by leveraging the use of subqueries [src](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtTipsAndTricksHowToHandleBandwidthLimitExceed) , thank you.